# Incorrect syntax near the keyword SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert-into

I try to group by my purchases by **hour** .In this case I lave number hours that I have not any purchase in it. I want check select query and if once of hours (**0 1 2 .... 22 23**  ) not exist into select query : add a record with default value into `@Table` .I  get this error :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword SELECT

How can i fix this?

```
    DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Price DECIMAL, NumberOfPhurchase INT, Hour INT);
    DECLARE @i AS INT = 0;
    DECLARE @j AS INT = 0;

    INSERT INTO @Table (Price,NumberOfPhurchase,Hour)
    VALUES
      (
        SELECT SUM(p.Price)    ,
           COUNT(p.Price)  ,
           DATEPART(HOUR, p.IssueDate)
    FROM   dbo.Payments    AS p
    WHERE  p.[state] = 6
           AND p.Transactionsuccess = 1
           AND (p.ReserveType = @ReserveType OR @ReserveType = 0)
           AND p.IssueDate >= @StartDate
           AND p.IssueDate <= @EndDate
    GROUP BY
           DATEPART(HOUR, p.IssueDate)

      )


    WHILE @i <= 23
    BEGIN
        SET @j =  
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Table 
        WHERE  @Table.Hour = @i;
        IF @j = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Table
              (
                Price,
                NumberOfPhurchase,
                Hour
              )
            VALUES
              (
                0,
                0,
                @j
              )
        END
        SET @i=@i+1;
    END
    SELECT
        @Table.Price,
        @Table.NumberOfPhurchase,
        @Table.Hour
    FROM
        @Table
```

Comment: Please narrow down the select statement

Comment: I'm 90% sure that it should go with `VALUES` keyword

Comment: You can do that in one step. Create a 'times' table that has 24 records numbered from 0 to 23 in it and just outer join to it. If you are interested in this method post back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop the word VALUES

```
INSERT INTO @Table (Price,NumberOfPhurchase,Hour)
    SELECT SUM(p.Price)    ,
       COUNT(p.Price)  ,
       DATEPART(HOUR, p.IssueDate)
    FROM   dbo.Payments    AS p
    WHERE  p.[state] = 6
       AND p.Transactionsuccess = 1
       AND (p.ReserveType = @ReserveType OR @ReserveType = 0)
       AND p.IssueDate >= @StartDate
       AND p.IssueDate <= @EndDate
    GROUP BY
       DATEPART(HOUR, p.IssueDate)
```

You can fill in the zero values with another INSERT .. SELECT statement:

```
  WHILE @i <= 23
  BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @Table(Price,NumberOfPhurchase,Hour)
       SELECT  0,0,@i
       WHERE @i NOT IN (SELECT Hour FROM @Table)
       SET @i=@i+1
  END
```

Comment: this is right but Now I have a same error on the   SET @j =  
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Table  statment

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake here is a non procedural solution. If you are going to use databases you should at least understand what I'm doing here:

```
INSERT INTO @Table (Price,NumberOfPurchase,Hour)
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(p.Price),0)    ,
       ISNULL(COUNT(p.Price),0)  ,
       H.HourNumber
FROM   
(
VALUES
(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),
(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23)
) H (HourNumber)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Payments    AS p
ON H.HourNumber = DATEPART(HOUR, p.IssueDate)
AND p.[state] = 6
AND p.Transactionsuccess = 1
AND (p.ReserveType = @ReserveType OR @ReserveType = 0)
AND p.IssueDate >= @StartDate
AND p.IssueDate <= @EndDate
GROUP BY
DATEPART(HOUR, p.IssueDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is TSQL, then instead of

```
SET @j =  
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Table
```

try:

```
SELECT @j = COUNT(*) FROM @Table
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with the code below (SQL Server 2016):

```
    DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Price DECIMAL, NumberOfPhurchase INT, Hour INT);
    DECLARE @i AS INT = 0;
    DECLARE @j AS INT = 0; 

    INSERT INTO @Table (Price,NumberOfPhurchase,Hour)
    SELECT SUM(p.Price)    ,
           COUNT(p.Price)  ,
           DATEPART(HOUR, p.IssueDate)
    FROM   dbo.Payments    AS p
    WHERE  p.[state] = 6
           AND p.Transactionsuccess = 1
           AND (p.ReserveType = @ReserveType OR @ReserveType = 0)
           AND p.IssueDate >= @StartDate
           AND p.IssueDate <= @EndDate
    GROUP BY
           DATEPART(HOUR, p.IssueDate)

    WHILE @i <= 23
    BEGIN
        SELECT @j =  
         COUNT(*) FROM @Table 
        WHERE  Hour = @i;
        IF @j = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Table
              (
                Price,
                NumberOfPhurchase,
                Hour
              )
            VALUES
              (
                0,
                0,
                @j
              )
        END
        SET @i=@i+1;
    END
    SELECT
       Price,
       NumberOfPhurchase,
       Hour
    FROM
        @Table
```

Comment: I suggest you learn to do this in one simple step using a tally table and outer join

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Are you giving me coding tips? :)

Comment: Sorry I thought you were the OP.. anyway this is a programmers procedural approach to what is normally achieved using a tally table and an outer join.